# time complexity : why O(nlogn)?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, logarithm

I have a document that says the average case time-complexity for the given code is O(nlog<sub>2</sub>n)

```
Random r = new Random();
int k = 1 + r.nextInt(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i += k);
```

I have computed the best and worst cases as:

Best case, `k = n` leading to time complexity of `O(1)`.

Worst case, `k = 1` leading to time complexity of `O(n)`.

How can average case be O(nlog<sub>2</sub>n), which is higher than the worst case. Am I missing something?

**Edit:**  The document could be prone to mistakes, so in that case what would be the average time-complexity of the above code, and why?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question correctly?

Comment: Yes, but the document could be prone to mistakes.

Comment: Looks like it can be O logN, if you get such a value of k. Basically, it would depend how the random numbers are being generated.

Comment: @uneq95 , yes O(logn) makes sense, but I would like proof/some explanation for it.

Comment: @Saad I have a proof in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a given value of k, the for loop runs n/k times. (I'm ignoring rounding, which makes the analysis a bit more complicated but doesn't change the result).

Averaging over all values of k gives: (n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n) / n. That's the n'th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). The harmonic numbers tend to log(n).

Thus the average runtime complexity of this code is log(n). That's O(log n) or equivalently O(log_2 n).

Perhaps your book had an additional outer loop that ran this code n times?